# Regarding batch inserts in hibernate in dependent tables in a single transaction

Tags: hibernate, insert

I have two tables tab1 ( id , col1 , col2) and then another tab2 ( id , col3,col4, tab_id) .This first table's id column is foreign key for the "tab_id" column of the second table tab2.
    Now I will be getting a input Json which will store the data in tab1 but it will 10,000 entries for tab2 table.I want to do multiple inserts on both the tables but in a single transaction using hibernate or JDBC batch inserts.So firstly need
    1. Single transaction for both tab1 and tab2 , ie if anything fails both transactions should be rolled back
    2. Batch inserts for tab2 table as dont want hit database 10,000 times for performance issues.
    I tried using  the below code but it didn't help.Any ideas how can I achieve this

```
Expected results to have data in tab1 and tab2 simultaneously in a single transaction and batch inserts in tab2 table



int batch_size=1200;

session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();

tx = session.beginTransaction();
Tab1 tab1= new Tab1 (); 
Integer structId =repo.getNextRecordId("Tab1"); //IN build method to get max(Id)+1 from the tab1 table
tab1.setId(structId);
tab1.setCol1(structInfo.getName());
tab1.setCol2(structInfo.getModule();
session.save(tab1);

List<DbObj>  mappingDetails = structInfo.getMappingDetails();
if(mappingDetails!=null && mappingDetails.size()>0){
    int recordCounter = 0;
    for(DbObj dbObj: mappingDetails){
        recordCounter++;
        Tab2 tab2= new Tab2();
        tab2.setTab1Id(structId );
        tab2.setCOl3(dbObj.getCol3);
        tab2.setCol4(dbObj.getCol4);
        session.save(tab2);                                                       
        if (recordCounter % batchSize == 0){
            session.clear();
            session.close();
        }
    }

}

tx.commit();
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the information for the tags you've used? Does your question relate to a Windows or DOS plain text script with a `.bat` or `.cmd` extension intended to run in `cmd.exe` or `commamd.com`?

Comment: This is just a sample code snippet of larger application which is deployed on a tomcat server.This is just a small piece that gets triggered with hitting data from RESTAPI.Not sure if that answers your question.
Moreover I am more intrested in finding the actual logic of accomplising it , ignore the way and where we are running it

Comment: No, it doesn't! Is this question related in any way to a script file named with a `.bat` or `.cmd` extension? If not, remove the tag, otherwise, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56909667/edit) to clarify that relationship.